# Use Experience Commerce 9 without SSL (for development)

Tags: sitecore-commerce

It's an recurring issue that certificates cause some setup trouble with (my) development environments.

So it would be nice to use Sitecore Experience Commerce 9, for development only, without certificates.

Is it possible to use XC9 without certificates?

Comment: Can you please tell us what the certificates issue you are experiencing ? We are in the year 2019 and there's should be no excuse to not run SSL everywhere including your own development environment within your pc.

Comment: I'm not sure how you setup your Sitecore Commerce. The way I'm setting up the Sitecore Commerce 9 in my local machine was through [Sitecore HabitatHome Utility](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Utilities). It will take care of the SSL certificate setup for you when installing Sitecore Commerce.

Comment: Certificates expire, access permissions might not be set, have to import certificates; it's just much simpler without.

Comment: I would also add that it's ideal to develop against an environment as closely matching Production as possible to ensure you catch any issues as early as possible. You will be using SSL in production, so I would recommend to develop using it as well to ensure no bugs related to this creep into your solution that you otherwise wouldn't see till you deployed to an environment with SSL enabled.

Comment: Just use a self signed cert. One thing I have found is to try to set up a few times without the use of any tools/scripts if you really want to understand the pitfalls here. There are plenty of blogs out there to point you in the right direction. This blog by Rameez is pretty good at explaining all certs as they relate to Experience Commerce 9. https://sitecoredude.com/the-dudes-guide-to-certificates-in-sitecore-experience-commerce-9/